Add a report to spreeCommerce Admin
What is the recommended way to add a report to Spree's admin area?
I can see the controller that adds them here:
https://github.com/spree/spree_backend/blob/main/app/controllers/spree/admin/reports_controller.rb
but doing this:
# /config/initializers/spree.rb
Spree::Admin::ReportsController.add_available_report!(:custom_report)

Gives error :
uninitialized constant Spree::Admin::ReportsController


Likely this is because you are trying to autoload a reloadable constant see Docs for options.
